# Basic source (include?) command equivalent in sql

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL. What is the source command (#include command) in postgre-sql? I want to divide my script into multiple files and tell SQL to execute scripts from part01.sql, part02.sql,....

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://serverfault.com/questions/356706/call-multiple-sql-files-in-a-single-sql-file-in-postgres

Comment: You do this with `psql` on the command line but probably not through pgAdmin or a similar tool.